# How to wait for all the data to be set before saving in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, express, asynchronous, mongoose

I am trying to set or udpate undefined (or defined) values in mongoose but I am having hard time because I need to await for the values. This code doesn't save the data, I think it is because the USER.save() executes before the values are set? How can I wait for the data to be udpated/set before saving?

```js
const USER = await User.findById(await UserID)

USER.authToken = await authToken,
USER.displayName = await name,
USER.profilePic = await pic
      
await USER.save()
```

Comment: Your issue is unclear. What's the problem having to use `await` for the values?

Comment: @robertklep I edited the original question to be little more specific.

Comment: It's still entirely unclear what the actual problem is. Where are `UserID`, `authToken`, `name` and `pic` coming from? Why are you using `await` for what _look_ to be just variables?

Comment: @robertklep they coming from external source I just simplified the question to make it easier to read, anyway I need to use await for them. So the main problem is that the data does not update with that code above, the USER is specific user from the database and I want to set or update the authToken, displayName and the profilePic for that specific user.

Comment: @vemmu your question isn’t still clear enough. Both the question and the code

Comment: By simplifying the question, you're making it unclear what the problem is. `await USER.save()` will only execute once the previous `await` statements have finished. If it doesn't, there's an issue with the code that you're not showing.

Answer (score -1):

Okay I got it figured, when the `authToken` was set it triggered the `.save()` method so I just added two more `.save()` and it works so I am happy. Sorry for being unclear in my question guys.

```
USER.authToken = await authToken
await USER.save()
USER.displayName = await name
await USER.save()
USER.profilePic = await pic
await USER.save()
```